# Is it possible in VS2013 to trigger Package Manager Console commands from command line using devenv

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, continuous-integration, nuget, devenv

I am trying to automate an internal process that we have in our project using CI.

We have a PowerShell script which which run in Package manager console and I need to run this script before CI builds my solution. I cannot use the normal PowerShell and my script needs certain IDE specific elements to work.

Tried googling and could not find any options for it. Does any one know any possible way to trigger these PowerShell scripts from command line?